# Self Joins in Mysql... How would I self join this table?

Tags: php, mysql, join, self

How would I `self join` a table to show the Name, employee number, manager's name of those who are managed by either `Blake or Jones`?

I'm trying to line it up in the following manner:

```
SELECT
FROM
INNER JOIN
ON
WHERE
```

The problem I am having is I have understood `MySQL` very well up until now, and I cannot seem to grasp the concept of the table joining itself.... any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `SELECT * FROM someTable t1 INNER JOIN someTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id`

Comment: This blog post explan joins: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/. Check it out and you will have great understanding of joins after that.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL self join that joins a table to itself using join

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 AS t1 
INNER JOIN table1 AS t2 
ON t1.col_name=t2.col_name 
WHERE t1.col_name='xyz'
```

Comment: We would normally use ON with [INNER] JOIN

Comment: Sorry typing mistake @Strawberry

Comment: please check again @CharlieHoward

Comment: Also, it's highly unlikely (although not impossible) that you would want to return all columns from both instances. This would create duplicate column names in the result set, which any application level code would struggle to parse.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.name,t1.employee_number,t1.manager_name from table t1 join

table t2 where t1.manager_name = t2. manager_name and t2.manager_name in

 ('Blake','Jones');
```